# using last successful run date for query in next run

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using **JdbcPagingItemReader** of Spring Batch for processing entries in my database. There is a timestamp column in the table I am querying and I want the JdbcPagingItemReader in the next run to just process the items **where timestamp > "last successful job execution"**

I think this should be a fairly common use case but somehow I can't figure out how to configure it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JdbcPagingItemReader` has it's own custom restart logic. It searches for the last retrieved value which maps to a unique index field and restarts the job from there.

From the [JavaDocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html):

> On restart it uses the last sort key
>   value to locate the first page to read
>   (so it doesn't matter if the
>   successfully processed itmes have been
>   removed or modified).

As you can see, your timestamp field would not make any significant difference.

---

Update after reading comment:

OK, then how about dynamically creating the where clause for your `PagingQueryProvider`?

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.spr...JdbcPagingItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.spr...SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="selectClause" value="select id, name, credit"/>
            <property name="fromClause" value="from customer"/>
            <property name="whereClause">
                <bean class="your.company.WhereClauseFactorybean" />
            <property />
            <property name="sortKey" value="id"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="status" value="NEW"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="customerMapper"/>
</bean>
```

Now implement `WhereClauseFactorybean` as a `FactoryBean` that uses `JdbcTemplate` to find the last timestamp and return something like `where timestamp > <your time stamp>` or `null` if no timestamp is found.

**Reference:**

- [Spring Batch:
  `JdbcPagingItemReader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#JdbcPagingItemReader)
- [Spring: `FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)
- [Spring: `JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate)

---

Update after reading more comments:

Then I guess you will have to [implement a custom `StepExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#stepExecutionListener), inject the [`AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider.html) into it and [set the where clause](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider.html#setWhereClause%28java.lang.String%29) in the [`beforeStep(StepExecution)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html#beforeStep%28org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution%29) method.

Comment: well, I do not want to restart the job, I want to run it again an hour later or on the next day - which is a new execution

Comment: thanks, I already tried this before asking the question, the problem with this is that the whereClause is only generated once on startup and not every time the job is executed

Comment: @Thomas Du bist ne harte Nuss :-) I've added more content to my answer

Comment: thanks very much for your help so far ... I think we are nearly there ;-) The last problem I have is that the JdbcPagingItemReader calls generateFirstPageQuery only once in its afterPropertiesSet method so any change to the where clause after this does not have any effect

Comment: @Thomas argh, that's ugly. I guess then you also have to inject the ItemReader bean, cast it to `InitializingBean` and manually call `afterPropertiesSet()` (at least that's a public method, but what a hack!!!)

Comment: yes that's ugly, but that seems to be the way to go ... now I "just" have to figure out how to get the date of the last successful job execution (this all seems very strange to me as I thought this is such a common use case for batch operations)

Comment: @Thomas you should probably file a feature request for this scenario